# Div with vertical scrolling

Tags: html, css

I need to implement an element with a left - right scroll effect, like this :
[image]

How can do this?

Here is my code :

```
<div class="populardiv">
   <div class=populart></div>
   <div class=populars></div>
   <div class=populars></div>
   <div class=populars></div>  
   <div class=populars></div>
   <div class=populars></div>   
</div>




.populardiv
{
    float:left;
    width: 100%;
    height: 35vw;
    background-color:white;
    overflow-x: scroll;        

}

.populars
{
    float:left;
    width: 20vw;
    height: 20vw;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: red;
    margin-left:3vw; 

}
```

My  output screen :

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: It depends on the device you are using for testing. Fix width somewhere then you will be able to scroll it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution :

```
<div class="populardiv">
   <div class=populart></div>
   <div class=populars></div>
   <div class=populars></div>
   <div class=populars></div>  
   <div class=populars></div>
   <div class=populars></div>   
</div>


<style>
.populardiv
{
   height: 35vw;
   background-color:white;
   overflow: auto;
   white-space: nowrap;
}

.populars
{
   width: 20vw;
   height: 20vw;
   border-radius: 50%;
   background-color: red;
   margin-left:3vw; 
   display: inline-block;
}
</style>
```

[JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/e6rj9q56/)

Answer (score 3):

Add `white-space: nowrap` to the container, and then change the child elements to `display: inline-block`, instead of `float`

```css
.populardiv {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  height: 35vw;
  background-color: white;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.populars {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20vw;
  height: 20vw;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: red;
  margin-left: 3vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="populardiv">
  <div class=populart></div>
  <div class=populars></div>
  <div class=populars></div>
  <div class=populars></div>
  <div class=populars></div>
  <div class=populars></div>
</div>
```